# Typescript destructuring deep import

Tags: typescript, import, module

I have a module of the shape:

```
{
  types: {
     interface MyType {}
  }
}
```

I would like to import MyType by its name into the module and use it.

I know i can import `types` and then do `types.MyType` but I would like to use the name of the type only.

We can't do a deep import like `import { types: { MyType } } from './module'`

And destructuring into a variable like so:

```
const { MyType } = types;
const the: MyType = {
  username: "user",
  password: "pass"
};
```

Results in the error `'MyType' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MyType'?`

How to do deep imports like this to use the type name directly?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-snyder-bmvh5?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: You can define an alias `type MyType = types.MyType;`. But any reason to wrap the types in "container" or it is 3rd party module?

Comment: Relevant feature request https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13135